# Need help looping some quotes

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to loop some quotes so they continue to display over and over but I'm having trouble, I have looked at some other posts on google and on here but can't work out how to change the codes on the posts to work with my code provides below. I have used a website called edit fiddle - JSFiddle to test the code and at the moment it just stops at the last quote. any help would be appreciated thank you.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 8000); // Change image every 10 seconds
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
}


/* Slides */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */

q {
  font-style: italic;
}


/* Add a blue color to the author */

.author {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="slideshow-container">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>I HATE EVERY MINUTE OF TRAINING. BUT I SAID, DON’T QUIT. SUFFER NOW 
    AND LIVE THE REST OF YOUR LIFE AS A CHAMPION.</q>
      <p class="author">- MOHAMMAD ALI</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>YOU’RE THE ONLY ONE WHO CAN MAKE THE DIFFERENCE. WHATEVER YOUR DREAM 
    IS, GO FOR IT. </q>
      <p class="author">– MAGIC JOHNSON.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>IF YOU TURN UP WORRYING ABOUT HOW YOU’RE GOING TO PERFORM, YOU’VE 
    ALREADY LOST. TRAIN HARD, TURN UP, RUN YOUR BEST AND THE REST WILL TAKE 
    CARE OF ITSELF. </q>
      <p class="author">– USAIN BOLT.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
      <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
      <span class="dot"></span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not looping because it's crashing due to an error in your script:

```
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
```

This will exceed the number of elements inside the array.

You can overcome this by checking it before incrementing:

```
  if (slideIndex+1 > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }else
  {
    slideIndex++;
  }
```

Additonally you're missing a span element class="dot", to match the number of quotes.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  if (slideIndex+1 > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }else
  {
    slideIndex++;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 10 seconds
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}

/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
}

/* Slides */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */

q {
  font-style: italic;
}

/* Add a blue color to the author */

.author {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>I HATE EVERY MINUTE OF TRAINING. BUT I SAID, DON’T QUIT. SUFFER NOW 
AND LIVE THE REST OF YOUR LIFE AS A CHAMPION.</q>
    <p class="author">- MOHAMMAD ALI</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>YOU’RE THE ONLY ONE WHO CAN MAKE THE DIFFERENCE. WHATEVER YOUR DREAM 
IS, GO FOR IT. </q>
    <p class="author">– MAGIC JOHNSON.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>IF YOU TURN UP WORRYING ABOUT HOW YOU’RE GOING TO PERFORM, YOU’VE 
ALREADY LOST. TRAIN HARD, TURN UP, RUN YOUR BEST AND THE REST WILL TAKE 
CARE OF ITSELF. </q>
    <p class="author">– USAIN BOLT.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
    <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
  </div>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this condition in your `showSlides()` function `if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}` to:

```
if (slideIndex > slides.length - 1) {
  slideIndex = 1;
}
```

to reset your slide index back to 1 so the slides can keep changing.

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 slides, but only 3 'dots'. When the 4th slide is showing, it tries to show the 4th dot which doesn't exist.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  // Hide all slides
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Hide all dots
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show current slide
  slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex].className += " active";

  // Increase slide index
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex == slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 0;
  }

  // Wait, then show next slide
  setTimeout(showSlides, 1000);

}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
}


/* Slides */

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Add an italic font style to all quotes */

q {
  font-style: italic;
}


/* Add a blue color to the author */

.author {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>I HATE EVERY MINUTE OF TRAINING. BUT I SAID, DON’T QUIT. SUFFER NOW AND LIVE THE REST OF YOUR LIFE AS A CHAMPION.</q>
    <p class="author">- MOHAMMAD ALI</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>YOU’RE THE ONLY ONE WHO CAN MAKE THE DIFFERENCE. WHATEVER YOUR DREAM IS, GO FOR IT. </q>
    <p class="author">– MAGIC JOHNSON.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>IF YOU TURN UP WORRYING ABOUT HOW YOU’RE GOING TO PERFORM, YOU’VE ALREADY LOST. TRAIN HARD, TURN UP, RUN YOUR BEST AND THE REST WILL TAKE CARE OF ITSELF. </q>
    <p class="author">– USAIN BOLT.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <q>I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work.</q>
    <p class="author">- Thomas A. Edison</p>
  </div>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>
```